# ReadConsoleInputW wrapper and ownership

Tags: windows, console, rust

I want to wrap the `ReadConsoleInputW` Windows console method into the `Read` trait so that I can use the `chars()` method, but I need also to know which key modifiers are applied (<kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>meta</kbd>).

One solution (like the one used by the Unix console) is to encode key events into control characters or ANSI escape codes.

Another solution would be to keep the key modifiers around but I can't make it work because the `chars()` method consume/move the input:

```
struct InputBuffer {
    handle: winapi::HANDLE,
    ctrl: bool,
    meta: bool,
}

impl Read for InputBuffer {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let mut rec: winapi::INPUT_RECORD = unsafe { mem::zeroed() };
        // kernel32::ReadConsoleInputW(self.0, &mut rec, 1 as winapi::DWORD, &mut count);
        // ...
        if rec.EventType != winapi::KEY_EVENT {
            continue;
        }
        let key_event = unsafe { rec.KeyEvent() };
        // ...
        self.ctrl = key_event.dwControlKeyState &
                       (winapi::LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED | winapi::RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED) ==
                       (winapi::LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED | winapi::RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED);
        self.meta = ...;

        let utf16 = key_event.UnicodeChar;
        // ...
        let (bytes, len) = try!(InputBuffer::wide_char_to_multi_byte(utf16));
        return (&bytes[..len]).read(buf);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let handle = try!(get_std_handle(STDIN_FILENO));
    let mut stdin = InputBuffer(handle);
    let mut chars = stdin.chars(); // stdin moved here
    loop {
        let c = chars.next().unwrap();
        let mut ch = try!(c);
        if stdin.ctrl { // use of moved value
            //...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

How to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put these flags into `Rc<RefCell<somestruct>>` and clone it before consuming `stdin`.

This is a common pattern that allows you to have "access" to the same data, from two places. `Rc` takes care of shared ownership, and `RefCell` checks if you don't have overlapping accesses.